How to determine multiplicative dependence of two algebraic numbers?
Given a pair of algebraic numbers $x,y \in \mathbb F^*$, where $\mathbb Q \subseteq \mathbb F \subset \mathbb C$, how can we find (or prove that there isn't) a pair of exponents $m,n \in \mathbb Z$ (not both $0$) such that
$$x^m \cdot y^n = 1 \; ?$$

In the single-variable case (i.e. setting $n = 0$, asking whether $x$ is a root of unity), with knowledge of cyclotomic polynomials, I suppose we could find all numbers $m$ whose totients $\phi(m)$ equal the degree of the minimal polynomial of $x$, and check whether $x^m = 1$, for these finitely many values of $m$.
In the case $\mathbb F = \mathbb Q$, by prime factorization, we can write
$$x = (-1)^{a_0} 2^{a_1} 3^{a_2} 5^{a_3} \cdots p_k^{a_k},$$
$$y = (-1)^{b_0} 2^{b_1} 3^{b_2} 5^{b_3} \cdots p_k^{b_k},$$
where the $a$'s and $b$'s are integers, so the equation $x^m y^n = 1$ is equivalent to the linear system of equations
$$m a_0 + n b_0 \equiv 0 \bmod 2, \quad m a_1 + n b_1 = 0, \quad m a_2 + n b_2 = 0, \quad\cdots,\quad m a_k + n b_k = 0.$$
For other number fields $\mathbb F$, perhaps we can do something similar with factorization?

For a concrete example, I'd like to prove that these two numbers on the unit circle,
$$x = \frac{\sqrt{50 + 10\sqrt5} + \sqrt{-50 + 10\sqrt5}}{10},$$
$$y = \frac{\sqrt{75 + 30\sqrt5} + \sqrt{-150 + 30\sqrt5}}{15},$$
are multiplicatively independent. These correspond to the sharp dihedral angles in the pentagonal cupola.
Equivalently, I want to prove that $u=-x^{-2}$ and $v=x^2y^2$ are multiplicatively independent:
$$u=\frac{-\sqrt5+2\sqrt5\sqrt{-1}}{5},$$
$$v=\frac{-\sqrt5+2\sqrt{-1}}{3}.$$
These correspond to the dihedral angles in the regular dodecahedron and icosahedron. Or, to simplify even further:
$$u^2=\frac{-3-4\sqrt{-1}}{5},$$
$$v^2=\frac{1-4\sqrt{-5}}{9}.$$
It's clear that these aren't roots of unity, since $u^2+u^{-2}=-\tfrac65$ and $v^2+v^{-2}=\tfrac29$ aren't algebraic integers. Also, since the only rational numbers on the unit circle are $\pm1$, it follows that $u^{2m}$ is not rational for $m\neq0$, so $\mathbb Q(u^{2m})=\mathbb Q(u^2)=\mathbb Q(\sqrt{-1})$. Similarly, $\mathbb Q(v^{2n})=\mathbb Q(v^2)=\mathbb Q(\sqrt{-5})$ for $n\neq0$. Any multiplicative dependence $u^{2m}v^{2n}=1$ would imply $\mathbb Q(u^{2m})=\mathbb Q(v^{-2n})$, but we know that $\mathbb Q(\sqrt{-1})\neq\mathbb Q(\sqrt{-5})$. Thus $u^2$ and $v^2$ are independent.
Hmm... That example was too "nice", allowing a specialized approach.
(We can also include the regular tetrahedron's dihedral angle:
$$w=\frac{1+2\sqrt{-2}}{3}.$$
By the same arguments, $\mathbb Q(w^l)=\mathbb Q(w)=\mathbb Q(\sqrt{-2})$ for $l\neq0$. Any multiplicative dependence $u^{2m}v^{2n}w^l=1$ would imply $\mathbb Q(w^{-l})\subseteq\mathbb Q(u^{2m},v^{2n})\subseteq\mathbb Q(u^2,v^2)$ (here we allow $mn=0$), but we know that $\mathbb Q(\sqrt{-2})\not\subseteq\mathbb Q(\sqrt{-1},\sqrt{-5})$. Thus the three numbers $u^2,v^2,w$ are independent.)

Here is a general algorithm, although applying it to your case seems laborious. We can work in the number field $K$ generated by $x$ and $y$. The first thing we can try is a generalization of your prime factorization argument for $\mathbb{Q}$: namely, $x$ and $y$ generate fractional ideals in $K$, and these fractional ideals have prime factorizations
$$(x) = \prod_i P_i^{e_i}, (y) = \prod_i P_i^{f_i}$$
where $P_i$ are prime ideals in $\mathcal{O}_K$ and $e_i, f_i \in \mathbb{Z}$. A necessary condition for an identity of the form $x^n y^m = 1$ (I have switched the names of your exponents, sorry) is that $(x)^n (y)^m = (1)$ as fractional ideals, which is equivalent to the vectors $(e_1, \dots e_k), (f_1, \dots f_k)$ being linearly dependent over $\mathbb{Q}$. From here we can distinguish three cases.
Case 1: These vectors are linearly independent. Then no such relation holds.
Case 2: These vectors are nonzero and there is some minimal linear dependence $(x)^n (y)^m = (1)$. This happens iff $x^n y^m = z \in \mathcal{O}_K^{\times}$ is a unit. Every linear dependence between $(x)$ and $(y)$ is a multiple of this one, so the question reduces to whether $z$ has finite order in $\mathcal{O}_K^{\times}$. This question is answerable by calculating the minimal polynomial of $z$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ (which can be done algorithmically in terms of minimal polynomials for $x$ and $y$) and checking whether it's a cyclotomic polynomial; if $z$ isn't a root of unity, typically you'll also be able to prove this by checking that $|z| \neq 1$, possibly after replacing $z$ with one of its conjugates.
Case 3: These vectors are zero. This happens iff $x, y \in \mathcal{O}_K^{\times}$ are both units. Now we can apply the Minkowski embedding
$$K \hookrightarrow K \otimes \mathbb{R} \cong \mathbb{R}^r \times \mathbb{C}^s.$$
The key point is that $\mathcal{O}_K$ sits inside $K \otimes \mathbb{R}$ as a lattice, in particular discretely. Hence $\mathcal{O}_K^{\times}$ is a discrete subgroup of $(\mathbb{R}^{\times})^r \times (\mathbb{C}^{\times})^s$ (this is the starting point of the proof of Dirichlet's unit theorem). Consider the homomorphism from this product to $\mathbb{R}_{+}^{r+s}$ given by taking absolute values pointwise; the kernel is compact (namely it is $\{ \pm 1 \}^r \times (S^1)^s$), so (I think) the induced map
$$\mathcal{O}_K^{\times} \to \mathbb{R}_{+}^{r+s}$$
has discrete image and kernel exactly its torsion subgroup. We have a further isomorphism $\mathbb{R}_{+}^{r+s} \cong \mathbb{R}^{r+s}$ given by taking logarithms, which reduces the question to understanding a discrete subgroup of $\mathbb{R}^{r+s}$, i.e. a lattice again. Such a subgroup is abstractly isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}^k$ for some $k$ (which in this case Dirichlet's unit theorem says is $r+s-1$), which means two elements in the image are linearly independent over $\mathbb{Z}$ iff they are linearly independent over $\mathbb{Q}$ or over $\mathbb{R}$.
Explicitly this means the following. Let $\sigma_i : K \to \mathbb{R}, \mathbb{C}$ be the real or complex embeddings of $K$ (which correspond to the factors of the Minkowski embedding). We associate to $x, y \in \mathcal{O}_K^{\times}$ the vectors $\log |\sigma_i(x)|, \log |\sigma_i(y)|$ in $\mathbb{R}^{r+s}$. Now we split into subcases.
Case 3a: These vectors are linearly independent. Then no relation holds.
Case 3b: These vectors are nonzero and there is some minimal linear dependence $n \log |\sigma_i(x)| + m \log |\sigma_i(y)| = 0$. This happens iff $z = x^n y^m$ lies in the kernel of the absolute value map, meaning it is a root of unity. Then some power of $z$ is $1$.
Case 3c: These vectors are zero. This happens iff $x, y$ are themselves roots of unity, in which case we have both $x^n = 1$ and $y^m = 1$ for some $n, m$.

 These arguments are structurally extremely similar and we can do them both in one step by considering the $P$-adic valuations and the real and complex embeddings simultaneously; this amounts to embedding $K$ into the adeles $\mathbb{A}_K$, although I'm less familiar with this.

In your case I can't easily tell what number field $K$ your $x$ and $y$ generate; I guess it's some iterated quadratic extension of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5})$. I think probably we end up in either case 1 or case 3a.

For the particular example, this might help: $x^4= -\frac{3}{5} + \frac{4}{5}i$. Now if we could  show that $y^n\not \in \mathbb{Q}(i)$ for all $n>0$. That probably follows from some basic field theory, looking at the minimal polynomial of $y$.
$\bf{Added:}$ The minimal polynomial of $z\colon = y^2$ is
$$45 t^4 + 60 t^3 + 46 t^2 + 60 t + 45$$
which factors into irreducibles over $\mathbb{Q}(i)$ as
$$[(3 + 6 i) t^2+ 10 t + (3-6i)][(3-6i) t^2+ 10 t + (3+6i)]$$
$z$ is a root of the first factor. To show that $z$ is not a root of a polynomial $t^n - s$, with $s \in \mathbb{Q}(i)$ it is enough to show that the ratio of the two roots of the first factor is not a root of unity. But that ratio is
$$\frac{3-6i}{(3+6 i) z^2}$$
with minimal polynomial
$$t^2-\frac{2}{9} t + 1$$
not even an algebraic integer.
Hence $z^n \not \in \mathbb{Q}(i)$ for all $n>0$ integer, done.

This would follow if we could compute the quadratic subfields of $\mathbb{Q}(y)$ (via the Galois correspondence, e.g.) and show that none of them are equal to $\mathbb{Q}(i)$. If that worked it would be easier than what I suggested!

@Qiaochu Yuan: Yes, that is a neat idea!
